# ¿Cómo calcular diferencia entre dos horas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero calcular la diferencia entre dos horas por ejemplo

08:00 y 9:30

Quiero obtener 01:30

Tengo el siguiente código para hacerlo pero no lo logro:

```
$("#hora_desde").on("change", function() {
  var hora_inicio = $(this).val();
  var hora_final = $("#hora_hasta").val();
  var aux1 = hora_inicio.split(":")[0];
  var aux1_1 = hora_inicio.split(":")[1];
  var aux2 = hora_final.split(":")[0];
  var aux2_1 = hora_final.split(":")[1];

  if (hora_final != null && hora_final != "") {
    var hora_diff = aux2 - aux1;
    var minuto_diff = aux2_1 - aux1_1;
    console.log(hora_diff+":"+minuto_diff);
    $("#horas_justificacion_real").val(hora_diff+":"+minuto_diff);
    $("#horas_justificacion_real").focus();
  }
});
```

El problema es que al restar de algo menor, se pone un signo menos por ejemplo 1:-30

**¿Como puedo lograr lo que necesito?**

Comment: Por qué no pruebas con moment.js? Se te haría mas fácil que con jquery y js nativo ya que es una libreria especializada para el tratamiento de variables de tiempo.

Comment: Deseas que se elimine el signo solamente? ¿ O validar que no salga negativo y muestre 0 en su lugar?  creo que me dejé llevar por la primera afirmación de eliminar el negativo _x

Comment: @Dev.Joel efectivamente lo que busco es que no se muestren negativos.

Answer (score 2):

Deberías calcular el número de minutos de la hora de inicio y final y calcular la diferencia a partir de ahí.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo en el que además se comprueba el formato de las horas y que la hora inicio sea anterior a la hora final:

```js
function calculardiferencia(){
  var hora_inicio = $('#hora_desde').val();
  var hora_final = $('#hora_hasta').val();
  
  // Expresión regular para comprobar formato
  var formatohora = /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/;
  
  // Si algún valor no tiene formato correcto sale
  if (!(hora_inicio.match(formatohora)
        && hora_final.match(formatohora))){
    return;
  }
  
  // Calcula los minutos de cada hora
  var minutos_inicio = hora_inicio.split(':')
    .reduce((p, c) => parseInt(p) * 60 + parseInt(c));
  var minutos_final = hora_final.split(':')
    .reduce((p, c) => parseInt(p) * 60 + parseInt(c));
  
  // Si la hora final es anterior a la hora inicial sale
  if (minutos_final < minutos_inicio) return;
  
  // Diferencia de minutos
  var diferencia = minutos_final - minutos_inicio;
  
  // Cálculo de horas y minutos de la diferencia
  var horas = Math.floor(diferencia / 60);
  var minutos = diferencia % 60;
  
  $('#horas_justificacion_real').val(horas + ':'
    + (minutos < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutos);  
}

$('#hora_desde').change(calculardiferencia);
$('#hora_hasta').change(calculardiferencia);
calculardiferencia();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="hora_desde" value="8:30" />
<input type="text" id="hora_hasta" value="9:30" />
<input type="text" id="horas_justificacion_real" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías validar si es negativo  *(<0)* antes de asignar al campo  `horas_justificacion_real` , si es así aplicar `Math.asb()` para eliminar el signo caso contrario, asignar directamente. Para ejemplificar apliqué el `on` a un `input` texto para el evento `input`.

```js
$("#hora_desde").on("input", function() {
  var hora_inicio = $(this).val();
  var hora_final = $("#hora_hasta").val();
  var aux1 = hora_inicio.split(":")[0];
  var aux1_1 = hora_inicio.split(":")[1];
  var aux2 = hora_final.split(":")[0];
  var aux2_1 = hora_final.split(":")[1];

  if (hora_final != null && hora_final != "") {
    var hora_diff = aux2 - aux1;
    var minuto_diff = aux2_1 - aux1_1;
    $("#horas_justificacion_real").val(
     ((hora_diff<0)? Math.abs(hora_diff) : hora_diff)+":"+ ((minuto_diff<0)? Math.abs(minuto_diff) : minuto_diff));

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="hora_desde" id="hora_desde" >
<input type="text" name="hora_hasta" id="hora_hasta" value="9:30">

<input type="text" name="horas_justificacion_real" id="horas_justificacion_real" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias construir objetos `Date` en base a la informacion disponible (horas y minutos). Si los restas, obtienes los milisegundos de diferencia, a partir de eso puedes obtener horas y minutos que es lo que buscas.

```js
function newDate(partes) {
    var date = new Date(0);
    date.setHours(partes[0]);
    date.setMinutes(partes[1]);
    return date;
}

function prefijo(num) {
    return num < 10 ? ("0" + num) : num; 
}

function calculardiferencia(){
  var dateDesde = newDate($('#hora_desde').val().split(":"));
  var dateHasta = newDate($('#hora_hasta').val().split(":"));

  var minutos = (dateHasta - dateDesde)/1000/60;
  var horas = Math.floor(minutos/60);
  minutos = minutos % 60;

  $('#horas_justificacion_real').val(prefijo(horas) + ':' + prefijo(minutos));
}

$('#hora_desde').change(calculardiferencia);
$('#hora_hasta').change(calculardiferencia);
calculardiferencia();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="hora_desde" value="8:30" />
<input type="text" id="hora_hasta" value="9:30" />
<input type="text" id="horas_justificacion_real" />
```

Answer (score -1):

new Date(new Date("fecha_final").getTime() - new Date("fecha_inicial").getTime())

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).